Discriminating union by parameter that is a union itself
I have an object that can have multiple types that can be discriminated through the "type" property. I want to write a function that would take a type as a parameter and return correctly typed item or undefined, depending if the initial object is currently the correct type, as follows:
type HorribleObject = {
    type: "foo",
    item: {
        foo: string
    }
} | {
    type: "bar",
    item: {
        bar: number
    }
} | {
    type: "",
    item: Record<string, never>
}


let objectIGet: HorribleObject = {type:"", item:{}}

// this works...
const getBarItem = 'bar' in objectIGet.item ? objectIGet.item.bar : undefined;

// ...but this doesn't
type GettableItemType = "foo" | "bar"
const getItemByType = (type: GettableItemType) => type in objectIGet.item ? objectIGet.item[type] : undefined;

Playground
When I hand-type every possible getter, everything is fine because then the discriminator in the 'bar' in objectIGet.item has a singular type "bar" and the compiler correctly assumes that the discriminated object I get is the one that has a property item.bar. But hand-typing a series of getters makes for a rather ugly code in a real-life scenario when there are many more possible types. While trying to write a generic function I unfortunately run into the following problem: because type is a union of strings, the discriminator type in objectIGet produces a union of object types. While we can quite safely assume that the object we get is the one that has the property passed in the params, the compiler simply doesn't know this.
Now, I can use an assertion in the function as follows:
const getItemByType = <T extends GettableItemType>(type: T) => 
    type in objectIGet.item 
    ? (objectIGet.item as Record<T, Extract<HorribleObject, {item: {[K in T]: any}}>["item"][T]>)[type] 
    : undefined;

Playground
This produces correctly typed results and seems to be a reasonable assumption, but somehow doesn't seem right. Is there some more correct way of doing this?

• Your first playground link seems to be outdated or incorrect. Please [edit] to fix it or maybe even just remove it. • The part that says "this works" seems to be unrelated to your question. It works because TS narrows objectIGet to {type: "", item: Record<string, never>} upon assignment. You probably don't want that (you can see that getBarItem is just of type undefined). Maybe you can [edit] to declare let objectIGet: HorribleObject; so there's no assignment narrowing.

(see prev comment) I'd say the issue is that TS doesn't discriminate unions by presence of keys, especially not for arbitrary union/generic keys. You could try to write a type guard function like hasKey as shown here and then you get something closer to your desired behavior. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
